# The ethics of “pulling out”

Tags: determinism, metaethics, abortion

This might seem trivial, but it’s earnestly been on my mind, so I do want to use it as an opportunity for philosophical learning.

Abortion is to me a very complex philosophical topic. I’ll only focus on one of myriad aspects commonly cited as a decision criteria for its ethicality.

People sometimes claim that an abortion amounts to a cancellation of a future, predetermined person’s life. You might think of it as a kind of “future-murder”.

In order to claim this, I think you need a developed theory of how ethics interacts with determinism and causality. Since, if when having unprotected sex, one may have the choice available to them to “pull out” or not (ie, climax in such a way that would likely lead to fertilization), we could ask if “pulling out” also amounts to “future-murder”.

I won’t go into details here about what frameworks could be used to analyze this problem deeper, but just wants to get the idea out of my head and out into the open, since it’s been rattling around in there for quite some time.

Comment: life begins at conception... or rather, i am shooting blanks

Comment: I do hope you are not going to ask me to start worrying about all the sperm that lose out in the race for the egg. I think I shall cling to my obstinate belief that it is not possible to murder someone who does not exisr.

Comment: Hi Julius, what is the question exactly?

Comment: @IdiosyncraticSoul https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzVHjg3AqIQ

Answer (score 2):

First of all "pulling out" is a pretty unreliable method of birth control...

But let's suppose that it would work. In the case of an abortion you would end a process that would otherwise likely result in a human being been born. In the case of interrupting the fertilization this whole process wouldn't have been started in the first place so you're not ending anything. You're eliminating one possible future, but your present state of being constantly annihilates infinitely many possible futures, so how is that any different.

Also with regards to ethics you might consider harm, suffering and agency and in either case giving birth might be immoral. Like you subject a being to a life of harm, suffering and you give them no agency in that. You start a process creating a being that had never any chance to express whether to be or not to be, but now that it is, it also can't stop being without harm and suffering. So either way that is incredibly selfish.

While depending on where you draw the cutoff range ending that process would reduce the harm and suffering as the mechanisms to feel it aren't yet developed but it likewise takes all the agency and gives none to the being that results out of the process and it might deprive them of all the joy and pleasantries that could also result out of that process.

In neither case can you plan ahead what live brings and whether you make them the greatest gift or the worst torture.

Answer (score 1):

Under consequentialism, there is no difference to the "future life" between having sex then getting an abortion, and not having sex (or having sex and not getting pregnant as a result of some precautionary measures).

When you set something in motion and stop it, the end result is the same as when you don't set it in motion. There may, of course, be effects of it having been in motion, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

You'd get into some weird territory if you try to apply this "future crime" idea consistently. Imagine being charged with "future theft" if you send a gift to someone without telling them and then cancelling the delivery before they receive or know about it. Imagine being charged with "future theft" for leaving a present in your home for them to find, but removing it before they find out about it.

Under this sort of thinking, there'd be blurry lines between criminalising abortion, banning birth control, and just forcing people to have sex. This may sound like an extreme comparison, but birth control is already restricted, if not outright banned, in some places, forced marriages exist, and there are at least a few prominent online figures (in the US and elsewhere) advocating for the idea that women don't have the right to say no to their partner (especially fundamentalist Christians who lean heavily on the idea that [wives should submit to their husbands](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%205%3A24&version=NIV), and such people tend to also oppose abortion, and often oppose birth control). Although many of these positions may not be motivated by wanting to protect a "future life" (but they tend to share a common theme of disregarding women's rights in favour of some other consideration).

---

There would be a difference if you give someone else an abortion without their consent, but no-one is suggesting that we do that* (or, at least pro-choice advocates don't want anything to do with anyone who suggests that). That, in turn, would have a similar result on the "future life" as stopping people from having sex. But the differentiating factor is that giving someone an abortion modifies their body, and we could grant some parental rights based on the present existence of a fetus (which you'd be violating by giving them an abortion without their consent).

* Putting aside what we should do about e.g. people who didn't or couldn't consent to sex, and who may be unable to make an informed decision about pregnancy, one way or the other.